# How to remove rows that match one of several regex patterns?

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed, pattern-matching

I have a tab-delimited text file and wish to efficiently remove whole rows that fulfil either of the following criteria:

- values in the `ALT` column that are equal to `.`
- values in the `NA00001` column and subsequent columns that have the same digit before and after either of the two delimiters, `|` or `/`, for e.g. `0|0`, `1|1`, `2/2` etc.

An example input file is below:

```
CHROM POS     ID        REF ALT    QUAL FILTER INFO                              FORMAT      NA00001        NA00002        NA00003
20     14370   rs6054257 G      A       29   PASS   NS=3;DP=14;AF=0.5;DB;H2           GT:GQ:DP:HQ 0|0:48:1:51,51 0|0:48:8:51,51 1/1:43:5:.,.
20     17330   .         T      A       3    q10    NS=3;DP=11;AF=0.017               GT:GQ:DP:HQ 0|0:49:3:58,50 0|1:3:5:65,3   0/0:41:3
20     1110696 rs6040355 A      G,T     67   PASS   NS=2;DP=10;AF=0.333,0.667;AA=T;DB GT:GQ:DP:HQ 1|2:21:6:23,27 2|1:2:0:18,2   2/2:35:4
20     1110696 rs6040360 A      .     67   PASS   NS=2;DP=10;AF=0.333,0.667;AA=T;DB GT:GQ:DP:HQ 1|2:21:6:23,27 2|1:2:0:18,2   2/2:35:4
```

Example output file is:

```
CHROM POS     ID        REF ALT    QUAL FILTER INFO                              FORMAT      NA00001        NA00002        NA00003
20     17330   .         T      A       3    q10    NS=3;DP=11;AF=0.017               GT:GQ:DP:HQ 0|0:49:3:58,50 0|1:3:5:65,3   0/0:41:3
20     1110696 rs6040355 A      G,T     67   PASS   NS=2;DP=10;AF=0.333,0.667;AA=T;DB GT:GQ:DP:HQ 1|2:21:6:23,27 2|1:2:0:18,2   2/2:35:4
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this?

Comment: Given the column-formatted data `awk` is likely going to be easier to use here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example doesn't appear to include any lines that meet the "values in the `ALT` column that are equal to `.`" criterion, or lines that *don't* meet the second criterion (except the header line). So I added some lines of my own to your example for testing; I hope I've understood your criteria.

The first criterion is easily matched by testing the particular field, if we're using something like awk: `$5 == "." {next}` in an awk script would skip that line. Just using a regular expression is pretty simple too: `^[^^I]*^I[^^I]*^I[^^I]*^I[^^I]*^I\.^I`, where `^I` is a tab character, matches lines with just "." in the fifth (ALT) field.

With strict regular expressions you can't express "the same digit before and after [a delimiter]" directly. You have to do it with alternation of sub-expressions with specific values: `0[|/]0|1[|/]1|2[|/]2`... But there are only 10 digits, so this isn't particularly burdensome. So, for example, you can do this filtering with one long egrep command line:

```
egrep -v '^[^^I]*^I[^^I]*^I[^^I]*^I[^^I]*^I\.^I|0[|/]0|1[|/]1|2[|/]2|3[|/]3|4[|/]4|5[|/]5|6[|/]6|7[|/]7|8[|/]8|9[|/]9' input-file
```

Obviously that's not something you'd want to type by hand on a regular basis, and isn't ideal for maintenance. A little awk script is better:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
# Skip lines with "." in the fifth (ALT) field
$5 == "." {next}
# Skip lines with the same digit before and after the delimiter in any field
/0[|/]0/ {next}
/1[|/]1/ {next}
/2[|/]2/ {next}
/3[|/]3/ {next}
/4[|/]4/ {next}
/5[|/]5/ {next}
/6[|/]6/ {next}
/7[|/]7/ {next}
/8[|/]8/ {next}
/9[|/]9/ {next}

# Copy all other lines to the output
{print}
```

I've put the individual digit checks as separate awk statements for readability.

With extended regular expressions (EREs), you *can* express "same character before and after the delimiter" directly, using a back-reference. Backreferences should be used with caution, since they can create pathological performance characteristics; and, of course, you'll have to use a language that supports them, such as perl. POSIX awk and Gnu gawk don't. Here's a Perl one-liner that handles the second criterion:

```
LINE: while (<STDIN>) { next LINE if /(\d)[|\/]\g1/; print }
```

That's probably not very good Perl - I almost never use the language - but it works in my testing. The `(\d)` matches and remembers the digit before the delimiter, and the `\g1` matches the remembered digit after the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -alnE '$F[4]  eq "."           and
            $F[9] =~ m!(\d)[|/]\1!  and
            $F[10] =~ m!(\d)[|/]\1! and
            say'
```

**Update**: Sorry the OP ask for the oposite...

```
perl -alnE 'say unless (
               $f[4] eq "."            or 
               ( $F[9]  =~ m!(\d)[|/]\1! and
                 $F[10] =~ m!(\d)[|/]\1! and
                 $F[11] =~ m!(\d)[|/]\1!
               )
            )'
```

or equivalent

```
perl -ane 'next if ( $f[4] eq ".");
           next if ( $F[9]  =~ m!(\d)[|/]\1! and
                     $F[10] =~ m!(\d)[|/]\1! and
                     $F[11] =~ m!(\d)[|/]\1! );
           print '
```

Comment: Do you mean `$F[4] eq "."`?

Comment: Added some example output

Comment: The second criteria is not very clear: `remove is ($4="."    OR ( $10=~ 1/1 AND $11 =~ 1/1))` . Right?

Comment: Sorry Brad: my bad -  $F[4] eq "."